# Event on Chart.JS's Bar Chart's mousein and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I've scoured the [bar chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) and [event](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html) docs (which I find a bit confusing) and I've been unable to figure out how to act on a mousein and mouseout event when hovering over a Bar chart's bars (not the legend!). Currently the closest I've been able to come is utilizing the callback on the tooltip like so:

```
options.tooltips = {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    fontColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem) {
            // flipping a bool here
        }
    }
};
```

This solution doesn't work well because without knowing when the pointer leaves the bar I don't know when to flip the bool back. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to my issue:

```
options.tooltips = {
    // Hide the tooltips
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    displayColors: false,
    callbacks: {
        labelTextColor: function () {
            return 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
        },
        labelColor: function () {
            return {
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
            }
        }
    },
    // Highlight the HTML elements on bar hover
    custom: function(tooltipModel) {

        if (tooltipModel.body === undefined) {
            // flip bool false
            return;
        }

        if (/* ... */) {
            // flip bool true
        }

        return;
    }
};
```